# 'Cloning' Ubuntu to my other PC?

Tags: clone

I searched here and see mention of Clonezilla and Remastersys - but nothing I found answered my question completely, so I ask:

My home PC is just a generic one, and now that I changed it to Ubuntu I really love how it's come out and how it runs better !

My office PC is a different generic set of hardware, and I'd like to 'clone' the exact same setup to it but not have to repeat all the tweaking and such that I did already.

Is there a program that will allow me to replicate/install my already customized setup from one to the other, easily ?
Are there certain steps I must make before doing something like that so it'll be compatible with different hardware ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you explain why Clonezilla and Remastersys do not meet your expectations?, Also generic is a generic term that is too generic for anyone to answer, so add your specs of both computers or the one you want to clone.

Comment: Home PC=>Asus MB/AMD CPU/Nvidia display card; Office PC MSI MB/AMD CPU/Nvidia display card. I've never used either program yet. My query is because I want to make sure that since they likely have different northbridge/southbridge chipsets that the restored configuration will be able to adjust if it must and boot up properly. Does that help ?  Thanks !

Comment: Mark, could you please update the Rescuezilla link you posted to https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/releases/latest ? The current latest (v1.0.5.1) has fixed some long-standing bugs that affected Redo Backup since its inception. Its recommend for all users to upgrade.

Comment: Link updated to https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/releases/download/1.0.5.1/redobackup-livecd-1.0.5.1.iso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ancient thread, I know - but as this is a forever needed function I am adding info here from my own experiences in the years since the OP.**

To resume here I must 1st mention that the best of what I've found & used taught me to stick with EXT3 as an important part of the process (and frankly I've seen nothing that has made me change that choice...).

**2 backup options have served me well most of the time between my additions here:**
A - Systemback
B - Macrium Reflect

**Details pertinent to the above:**
Systemback required some digging & learnings both to get it up & running on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 - and to learn its foibles.

That having been done, it is amazingly excellent for cloning an entire system & I've used it for that many times already with 100% success.
Its single limitation is that for backups over 4GB it will not make an ISO, so those must be written to a USB stick - which is great anyhow as it makes a terrifically usable boot media that does both live and installable sessions.

Reflect is ONLY used via boot media as it is winpe3, but it does handle up to EXT3 for me without fail - with the only possible problem afterwards of sometimes needing to also use Boot Repair Disk to correct GRUB2.
(It also takes WAY longer to boot up than just using the already installed Systemback...)

**Very important to mention here is the reincarnation of ReDo !!**
I have gotten it & made a boot media from it, but have yet to test & verify it for myself - so, it is definitely very happy news for it to be back, but please also remember - YMMV.

Back when I posted the above answer I did truly adore ReDo Backup, it was so easy & simple & it just worked.
Then, after the days of Ubuntu 12.04 it was abandoned.

Now, at long last it has been brought back from the dead - YAY !!!

For anyone interested, have a look at these pages:

Home page=>
https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla

FAQ=>
https://rescuezilla.com/help.html

Limitations=>
https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/wiki/Rescuezilla-Limitations

Release =>
https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/releases/download/1.0.5.1/redobackup-livecd-1.0.5.1.iso
(From https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/releases )

**My own cloning process goes this way:**
I have taken my time to create a tweaked up version of 18.04.3, backed it up with Systemback - and transferred it with 100% success to a bunch of desktop as well as notebook PCs with various h/w.

Some were 100% new & just built (bare metal...), some were bought bearing the abortion called '10' which was sanitized away 1st (without ever even getting booted up to it), and the cloned system has been dropped into older h/w as well - and just works.

Please bear in mind that my solution INCLUDES the home partition which has NOT been used to store any personal data before the cloning process so that all settings in there are reproduced - which makes the outcome arrive as a system that takes very little time to finish setting up per-user.

*I hope all of this added info will be helpful for other folks here !!*

Answer (score 4):

You can't be sure 100% that they'll work since it's different hardware, but here comes the interesting part Ubuntu will load the correct Modules for the hardware its running so the only thing you can do is just, try it and see if it works, now the configuration files are in your home folder under several hidden folders (.config for example).

A personal experience on this: I had a Core2Duo, MSi Intel motherboard and an AMD GPU running Ubuntu 11.04, when the time arrived I upgraded to an AMD PII x6, AMD Mb and the AMD GPU, luckily Ubuntu worked for me so, as i said.. try it.

Comment: Excellent advice - I shall have to just try it then !!! I will be over-writing my current XP and I was worried I might have a non-bootable PC...but I think it is worth trying, and if I can make it into a live, bootable DVD it should show me if it will boot before I commit to it anyhow, I'm guessing...  Thanks !

Comment: I just did this over the weekend... took an existing system, cloned it using Clonezilla to an external drive, then restored in on totally different hardware... worked right out of the box... Actually pretty amazing

Comment: Thanks Kendor - that is very encouraging information !!!

Comment: I was severely disappointed with Remastersys because I have a spare partition with lots of stuff stored in it - and there's no way to tell it NOT to back that up - which was further complicated by it telling me my data was too big for a CD...WHAT ?? A CD ??? I had a writable DVD in the burner and I guess it doesn't 'speak' DVD sometimes, so I just gave up on it. Glad I did too, as that brought me to Redo which is way better.

Answer (score 1):

I tried CloneZilla and it failed to complete; searching for the error it threw proved to be a waste of my time...

Moved on to Remastersys and found that it is so primitive and lacking in options as to be useless; meaning that it cannot be told WHAT & WHERE to back up...feh.

**The best solution I've found:**

Redo Backup [(here)](http://redobackup.org/)- holy cow is this great !!!
I was able to make my backup to my USB stick in an amazingly short period of time, and restored it quickly as well - if there's anything else equal or better than Redo Backup I'd love to hear of it, but for now I am very, very satisfied.

Comment: I was going to suggest an edit but I'm not sure what's going on... Your link redirects to a blog post titled "Top 10 Best Backup and Recovery Software" and they have [this Redo Rescue](http://redorescue.com/) listed there, is it the same Redo Backup that you mention?

Comment: AFAIK Redo Rescue is an updated reboot of the original Redo. I've used it & it worked quite well. Nowadays I keep a spare, externally connected regular HDD that is cloned to by using Macrium Reflect from my running OS. If/when some disaster occurs I then simply connect & use that clone. Lots has changed in the 10+ years since I originally posted here !!

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully moved Ubuntu installations to different hardware several times. Typically I would image the drive(s) as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) There are however, some caveats. It's been my experience that difficulties can arise if the video and networking hardware are too different.