# When Cloning Linux Systems

Tags: clone

Assuming you want to use the same OS type on each computer (Ex: Intel x32 bit), is it possible to clone one linux file system of one computer (IE the entire OS) to another computer's hard drive that is a different brand and model computer from the first one? When Ubuntu installer installs Ubuntu on the computer, does it set it up so it can only run on (for the conversation, a Compaq Presario) to where if I tried to clone the Compaq's hard drive to a (for say, a Sony's computer) hard drive Ubuntu wouldn't run properly on the Sony? I guess the short version of the question is- can you clone a linux OS from one computer to another computer that is a different model and manufacturer than the first one? Thanks:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Cloning' Ubuntu to my other PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133565/cloning-ubuntu-to-my-other-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 questions:

- "will Ubuntu installed on one computer work well if somehow "cloned" or "transferred" to another computer?" - the answer to this is usually YES, it works amazingly well.
- "how to clone a Ubuntu installation from one machine to another, provided the second one runs Windows and I can't boot that second machine from CD/USB" (I guessed the last part from your [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207924/uninstall-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-with-windows)) - the answer to this one is "it might be tricky". It would be much easier to pull the hard drive out of machine which doesn't boot from CD/USB and transfer it to machine which can be booted from CD/USB

Comment: Very good :)
So your thinking I should wipe the hard drive with Windows on it and make a clone of the hard drive with Ubuntu on it? Not a bad idea...

Comment: Or transfer it... that works too :)

Comment: I was thinking about getting the hdd out of machine, putting it into another machine which does boot from CD/USB (disconnecting that machine's hard drive temporarily), booting from CD/USB, making  a fresh install on the hard drive (wiping Windows in the process), then shutting the machine down and moving the hard drive back to its "home" machine. This would be much easier than cloning OSes or doing a Wubi install and then transferring it to a partition.

Comment: I see your logic here, and I would do this if I had another desktop to play with. I make a pretty bad nerd.. XD